# Why we still diagonalize compact operators even tho we lack invertibility.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, math-history

We know that any compact symmetric operator on a Hilbert space, has a orthogonal base of eigenvectors. But we also know that $0$ is in the spectrum if $X$ is infinite dimensional, which makes the operator non-invertible(in particular they are never surjective).

Question;

Why we would care to diagonalise in infinite dimensional at all since never get as good info as in finite dimension (non-zero eigenvalues on the diagonal).

Added later ;

Plausibel answer or claim ;

Diagonalisation of a compact operator $C$ in infinite dimensions seems more related to the invertabiity(or solvability) of Iλ−C (a fredholm equation of 2nd kind) for compact operator C rather then properties of C itself as a linear map which often is the object of intrest in finite dimension i.e linear algebra. That might be a reason for my confusion. From a historcial point of view we seem to care about solvability of Iλ−C and qualitive properties of solutions rather then C itself as a map from one vector space into another,in some sense. So when we "diagonalize" we really just cheack solvabilty of Iλ−C, we are not looking for a nice bijection(the full diagonal matrix) of the vectorspaces as we do in linear algebra.

Or simply the MAIN reason we started to study the spetrum of an operator $C$ was to determine if $I \lambda - C$ is solvable.

Am I on to something or just way off?

Comment: You mean "*compact* diagonal operators" in the title?  Certainly there are plenty of invertible diagonal operators (e.g. the identity operator), which are not compact.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes and thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking - why would this fact make diagonalization less useful?  But it may help to consider that a typical example of a compact diagonal operator is one where the $n$th diagonal entry is $1/n$.  None of the eigenvalues is 0 (this operator is injective) but they are getting very close.  This basically has to happen: the diagonal entries must be a sequence approaching 0.

Comment: @NateEldredge I guess I would like diagonalisation to lead to some kind of simple bijection as in finite dimension. I cant see what we gaining in this case?

Comment: What bijection are you talking about?

Comment: @NateEldredge a diagonal matrix as a function on $R^{n}$ is a bijection right? Given that we have no zeros on the diagonal ofc.

Comment: At some level, there are just fundamental differences between finite and infinite dimensions that you have to get used to.  In any dimension, it's true that a diagonal matrix with no zeros on the diagonal corresponds to an *injective* function.  In finite dimensions, any injective linear map from a space to itself is also surjective, but in infinite dimensions this is false.

Comment: @NateEldredge I know, im just tying to see why things fail and how we try to immitate the situation and what properties our immitation has.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think I just realized something. Diagonalisation in infinite dimensions seems more related to the invertabiity of $I \lambda - C$(a fredholm equation of 2nd kind) for compact operator $C$ rather then properties of $C$ itself which often is the object of intrest in finite dimension i.e linear algebra. That might be a reason for my confussion. We seem to care about solvability of   $I \lambda - C$ and qualitive properties of solutions  rather then $C$ itself in some sense.

Answer (score 3):

For any bounded selfadjoint operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $X$, you can reduce to the case where $T$ is injective because $X=\mathcal{N}(T)\oplus\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}$ and both of these closed subspaces are invariant under $T$. That allows you to reduce to looking at $T$ on the Hilbert space $Y=\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}$, and $T$ remains selfadjoint on this invariant subspace.

The operator $T : Y\rightarrow Y$ has dense range and is injective. If the range of $T$ is closed, then $T$ is a topological isomorphism, which means that the unit ball of $Y$ is compact, leading to the conclusion that $Y$ is finite-dimensional. Otherwise, the range of $T$ cannot be closed, which means that $0 \in\sigma(T)$.

Comment: I been trying to understand $X=\mathcal{N}(T)\oplus\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}$. But cant seem to manage :/

Comment: @User2313 : For any bounded operator $T$, you have $(Tx,y)=(x,T^{\star}y)$. Therefore $y \perp \mathcal{R}(T)$ iff $(x,T^{\star}y)=0$ for all $x$, which holds iff $T^{\star}y=0$. So $\mathcal{R}(T)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(T^{\star})$. So $\overline{\mathcal{R}(T)}=\mathcal{N}(T^{\star})^{\perp}$.

Comment: Dont you need to assume compactness of $T$ in the second paragraph?

Comment: @User2313 : The compactness comes in at the point of noting that $Y$ is finite-dimensional if $T$ is compact and has a closed range.

Comment: Very nice, do you have some motivation for the reason why still diagonalise? As you can see in comments this is somthing which puzzles me and maybe some clarification what I mean by "good info".

Comment: As I worte to Nate ; "I think I just realized something. Diagonalisation in infinite dimensions seems more related to the invertabiity of Iλ−C(a fredholm equation of 2nd kind) for compact operator C rather then properties of C itself which often is the object of intrest in finite dimension i.e linear algebra. That might be a reason for my confussion. We seem to care about solvability of Iλ−C and qualitive properties of solutions rather then C itself in some sense."      Whats your take on that?

Comment: @User2313 :This machinery grew out of trying to understand and justify Fourier's separation of variables techniques for solving Partial Differential Equations. Compact operators came out of Fredholm studying nice integral operators to deal with Fourier problems, and he was the first use a "resolvent." Riesz generalized this apparatus to define compact operators, and perfectly characterized the Fredholm alternative. But people would rather not return to the detailed examples any more, which is part of the random walk of Math where history is forgotten. Details of specific problems remains hard.

Comment: Im not after understanding the detalis of every operator and how this works in general. It just stuck me as kind of wierd to diagonalize an operator which were never invertable, but as I written above the reason  that we look at the spectrum might been to get info reagarding $I \lambda - C$ not  $C$ itself. I.e oppose to the general point of view in basic linear algebra where we study $I \lambda - C$ to understand $C$.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for intuition so I am going to allow myself to play a little loose...

Let $U$ and $V$ be  infinite vector spaces with a countable bases $\{e_i\}$ and $\{f_i\}$. Suppose that a linear map $T:U\rightarrow V$ is diagonalisable such that

$$T\left(\sum_i\alpha_i e_i\right)=\sum_i\alpha_i \lambda_i f_i.$$

If none of the $\lambda_i$ are zero, and so $T$ invertible, then the range of $T$ will be in a closed ball of infinite dimension and so $T$ cannot be compact.

Comment: This is nice but it does not adress what Im asking.

Comment: Perhaps your title and question at odds? Does this not answer your title?

Comment: It answers the title yes, but not the questions in the question.

Comment: Fair enough. Good luck with the question. You should perhaps change the title to "Why do we diagonalise linear maps between infinite dimensional spaces?".

Comment: Your right, Im thinking of a better title. Sry about that.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your intuition, but it was quite a lot since I studied topology so I don't exactly remember... doesn't some Tychonoff theorem says that even an infinite dimensional space can be compact?

Comment: @Dac0 my understanding is that Tychonoff's Theorem says that the product of compact spaces is compact... but the closed unit ball in infinite dimensions can not be written as such a product.

Comment: That's also true :D :D :D